# Why does adding {12pt} cause a compiler error?

Tags: errors, compiling

```
\documentclass{12pt}{article}

\title{Testing}

\author{Bob }

\date{July 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I am compiling using sharelatex.com, but I am getting a compiler error saying that the compiler cannot find the file that I am trying to include. However, I am not trying to include any files.

The error occurs when I include the text `{12pt}` in the `\documentclass`. For example, the program works when I change the first line to `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: it's `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` with [12pt]

Comment: In LaTeX, brackets `[...]` are used for optional arguments to commands, while `{...}` braces are used for required arguments. In many cases `[...]` are used to pass configuration options (such as in `\documentclass` or in `\usepackage`) which can be omitted if you just want to use the default. In your case `12pt` is an option specifying the font size to use, and should be passed in brackets and not braces.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because itis solved by comments.